# Javafx Spring Boot - Error When running Application

Tags: java, spring, javafx

This is my first time using Javafx with Spring Boot 
I'm have the below error when running my Application

```
Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.0.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project basic: Could not exec java: Application finished with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
```

The Main Class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class BasicApplication extends Application {

private Parent root;
private ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

@Override
public void init() throws Exception {
    context = SpringApplication.run(BasicApplication.class);
    FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Scene.fxml"));
    loader.setControllerFactory(context::getBean);
    root=loader.load();
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

@Override
public void stop() throws Exception {
    context.close();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(BasicApplication.class,args);
}
```

}

Controller Class

```
public class SceneController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private Label label;

@FXML
private void buttonAction(){
    label.setText("Hello World!");
} 

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
}
```

}

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>basic</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>basic</name>
<description>Basic project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <fork>true</fork>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Please what is going on.
Why org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.0.RELEASE:run can't be executed?

Scene.fxml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" fx:controller="com.example.SceneController">
<children>
    <Button layoutX="126" layoutY="90" onAction="#buttonAction" text="Click Me!" />
    <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="126" layoutY="120" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" />
</children>
```

am running the application with NetBeans IDE

Comment: how are you running the project? are you running a command like __mvn clean spring-boot:run__ ? Could you show the project structure?

Comment: no. am running it with netbeans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok have seen why the error occur. I didn't include `@Component` in the Controller Class. my Mistake.

```
@Component
public class SceneController implements Initializable {
   @FXML
   private Label label;

   @FXML
   private void buttonAction(){
        label.setText("Hello World!");
   }

   @Override
   public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
         // TODO
   }

}
```

`Now Everything is working fine

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed you have not shown your Scene.fxml file (the one that specifies the layout of your app) or your project's directory structure.

Check that you have a Scene.fxml file in the /src/main/resources/fxml/ directory.

I've run your code including in my machine creating a base project with https://start.spring.io/ , using this as Scene.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx">
    <Label text="Main Content"/>
</AnchorPane>
```

and running the command **mvn clean spring-boot:run** and it works fine.

Check if you have the JAVA_HOME environment variable correctly configured.

follow this link for an introduction into javafx with spring boot:
https://wimdeblauwe.wordpress.com/2017/09/18/using-spring-boot-with-javafx/

Hope this helps.

Comment: added the Scene.fxml (see edit). am actually using netbeans to run the project. thanks for your response i will go thru that link